# facebook like button only showing up for my account not for other users

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating an fb app , I just want to navigate to next page if the user already liked my page and for not liked user only onclick of like it will go to the next page . this code is working fine for my account but not for others . Can you please help me out .

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '657165490961669', 
      channelUrl : 'https://www.facebook.com/cypiyow', 
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true, 
      xfbml      : true  
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      var page_id = "228530813943529";
      if (response && response.authResponse) {
        var user_id = response.authResponse.userID;
        var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
        FB.Data.query(fql_query).wait(function(rows) {
          if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
        window.location = "email_form.php";
          } else {
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            window.location = "email_form.php"; 
        }
    );

          }
        });
      } else {
            //error message 
      }
    });
  };

  (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me either since the page_id does not exist (or only you have permission to view it). Can you be more precise: what part of the cod doesn't work, are there any error messages in the browser console,...

Answer (score 1):

in your app's settings in the facebook developer area, is this app in sandbox mode?   that would cause it to only be available to you,   if that is what you mean when you say it is only working for you.   you would need to add some testers in your app settings or move out of sandbox mode